# Derivative of L1-loss

Tags: analysis, derivatives, neural-networks

If `y` is the ground truth label vector and `ŷ` the predicted label vector.

Then `L1(ŷ) = ||ŷ - y||_1 = (|ŷ_1 - y_1| + ... + |ŷ_n - y_n|)` (L1-Norm).

But what is the derivative of `L1(ŷ)` w.r.t `ŷ`?

We know the L2-Loss `L2(ŷ) = (||ŷ - y||_2)^2` where the derivative w.r.t to `ŷ` is `2*(ŷ - y)` and I would like to calculate the same for `L1`.

Any tips are greatly appreciated.

Comment: It would help us help you if you tell us what you know about Calculus. In particular, do you understand that some functions have no derivative?

Comment: Yes I know that the L1-Norm of one value cannot be derived because it is not continuous at `x = 0` but I thought this may be different if we no longer talk about a single value but about a loss-function which "compares" two vectors. I hope this makes sense? Sorry of this sounds dumb.

Comment: When you use vectors as function arguments instead of single variables, you advance to multivariate calculus... which is more complicated, not less. Think that your loss function should be differentiable in each component of the vector (which is not) and even then... BTW the function _is_ continuous.

Comment: Okay thank you very much for your detailed answer. Do you mind explaining how the anomaly at x = 0 is called?

Comment: It depends on the source. _Singularity_ is often used, although ambiguous.